# Returning Data from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. I have an array. It looks like this.

```
$state=[
1 => "Utah"
  2 => "California"
  3 => "Nevada"
  6 => "Arizona"
]
```

I am trying to query the table in a database called a county. I want to display all the county that falls in those states which are in the array.

I write a code like this

```
 foreach($state as $st) {
      $data= DB::table('state')->Select(County)->where('name','=', $st)->get();
      dd($data);
  }
```

This is the code that I wrote. It does only return for the first state then after that, it gets stopped can someone help me. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using dd() inside the foreach loop and it stops the execution of your code. Also you are assigning the result of one query to a variable $data and even if you put dd() out of the loop you will get only the last result. So you must also make your variable $data an array and insert the results in it like this `$data[]= DB::table('state')->Select(County)->where('name','=', $st)->get();`

Comment: If the table is called `'county'`, you should use `DB::table('county')` instead `DB::table('state')`. Can you show us the table structure?

Answer (score 0):

It stops because dd() is dump and DIE. So it is like you would call:

```
dump($data);
die();
```

Try something like:

```
$query= DB::table('state');

foreach($state as $st) {
   $query->orWhere('name','=', $st);
}

$data = $query->get();
```

It will make one DB call instead of X calls and returns a collection of records with which you can work.

Comment: When i do that, It returns me an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
DB::table('country')->whereIn('name', array_values($state))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give categories to filter and next join eachother

App\YourModel::select('what you want')->join('category','your_models.id','=','category.your_model_id')->get();